# Error with usage of int() in Python (QPython)

Tags: python-3.x, qpython3

I have a pretty strange problem with `int()` Sometimes, even if it's really just numbers, I'm getting the error

> "[...] In line 2: Invalid literal with Base 10: '' "

But the value is just a number (0)
It's so strange... 
The following code causes this error:

```
count = open('count.dat', 'r')
cint = int(count.read)
cint = cint + 1
count.close()
del(count)
countw = open('count.dat', 'w+')
countw.write = str(cint)
countw.close()
del(countw)
```

PS: I'm a newbie

Comment: Can you provide what is in the count.dat

Comment: `""` seems like a emtpy string to me, I have a hard time converting that to a valid integer. Perhaps you got an empty string when the file is completely read? or is it a space `" "` either way, it's hard to convert text to a number when there are no (hex) numbers in it.

Comment: Uhmmm... The File does contain the number 0

Comment: The only thing count.dat contains is 0

Comment: `int(count.read)` converts a member function of a file instance function to int... perhaps you mean `int(count.read())` instead

Comment: In correct usage (when the value count is set correctly) count.read represents everything in the given file

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I tested int(count.read()) now, and it's still giving me this error

Comment: Quick lil' update: the error persists, even after changing int(count.read) to int(count.read())
I just don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

I thnk your code `cint = int(count.read)` , `countw.write = str(cint)` these lines should change

```
count = open('count.dat', 'r')
cint = int(count.read()) # as this 
cint = cint + 1
count.close()
del(count)

countw = open('count.dat', 'w')
countw.write(str(cint)) #as this
countw.close()
del(countw)
```

then it will work fine

before run the code

[image]

After running
[image]

if you count.dat file is blank obviously it will give the error int() with base 10: ''

Comment: for the initial run you setting the dat file 0 right?

Comment: before I ran this script, I ran another script which replaces everything in count.dat by 0

Comment: As I mentioned before, another script, which ran before sets count.dat to 0 but even if I run your improved script after it, I'm still experiencing this error

Comment: if you using any IDE or some thing or if you can check before running the above script the value in the count.dat exactly 0 or " " then you can figur out the issue I think to check whether previous  script making the count.dat 0

Comment: Actually, the count.dat was blank, when I checked it. That's confusing, because in the 1. Script, I clearly wrote "0" (without the ") in the count.dat file.

Comment: then you have to check that script why its not setting it properly

Comment: I checked the script 3 times, and I'm sure it should work. But it doesn't

Comment: Is this issue Fixed?